# PHP Search Results - Retrieve Data based on ID in URL

Tags: php

I have a PHP search function which retrieves items from my database and displays them on a search results page. When clicking on a search result, it currently takes you to a separate html page (for each search item) which contains further details about the item.

I would like to link each search result to one PHP page which gets the item ID from the URL and then retrieves and displays the relevant data from the database.

Below is the PHP code from the page which displays the search results, but I am not sure where to edit this, to link each item to the dynamic PHP page and then retrieve the ID from the URL on the dynamic PHP page?

```
<?php
if (!empty($data)){
foreach ($data as $item){
echo '<div class="item">';
if (strlen($item['item_image']) > 10){
if(strlen($item['item_link']) > 10){
echo '<a href="'.$item['item_link'].'">';
}
else {
echo '<div class="fail ">No Results Found;
}
?>
```

Edit:

I have used the below code on the detail_page.php

```
<?php $db =
mysql_connect("","","") or die("Database     Error");
mysql_select_db("items",$db); $id =     $_GET['id']; $id =     mysql_real_escape_string($id); $query =     "SELECT * FROM `items-one` WHERE `id`='"     . $id . "'"; $result = mysql_query($query);
```

But now need to call all of the row fields from the ID in the database and then add them at various points throughout the page?

Comment: put some anchor text to appear and close the anchor `click here</a>`

Comment: you can work with a $_GET parameter here change your link to this href="'detail.php?show='.$item['item_link'].'" then on the detail page you can listen to a $_GET change and alter the SQL query to only search for the id you received in the $_GET parameter ['show']

Answer (score 1):

Typically this is done by passing an id in a parameter via GET.  So links on the listing page may look like this:

```
echo '<a href="/path/to/detail_page.php?id=' . $id . '">' . $link_text . '</a>';
```

Here `$id` and `$link_text` maybe be populated in loop or whatever.

On `/path/to/detail_page.php` page you would have some code like this:

```
// validate that there is an integer-like value passed in `$_GET['id']`
// if so, set value to $id
$id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
// see results of filtering and behave accordingly
if (is_null($id)) {
    // $_GET['id'] was not set
    // do something and exit
} else if (false === $id) {
    // the value at $_GET['id'] didn't pass validation filter
    // do something and exit
}

// $id has a good integer value
// note you would probably need additional validation checks on the id value
// i.e. make sure value is not negative or 0
// you may want to cast $id to int to make these checks
// for example:
$id = int($id);
if ($id < 1) {
    // bad $id value
    // do something and exit
}
// read data from DB and display it
```

Comment: Thanks I have linked the detail page to the search results. How would I request for example the field, item_description from the database using the ID?

Comment: @MikeE The same way you would interact with the database to generate the page that list all the various items - you write a query against the database, but in this case you would query with a WHERE filter for id=? (where ? is the id value).  If you are asking how to work with a database in PHP, that is a very broad question with thousands of code examples out there.  Just look at examples that don't use deprecated `mysql_*` extension.